# Explain why margin in pixel and percentage produces different result in CSS?

Tags: html, css

This is the only HTML code on my page:

```
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}

#mydiv {
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

It produces following output:

[image]

When I change `margin: 10px;` in my above code to following :

```
#mydiv {
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 2%;
}
```

It results following:

[image]

You can clearly see the difference i.e. `margin: 2%;` applies more margin (space or gap) in contrast to `margin: 10px;`. The `#mydiv` displaces more towards bottom and right side.

Why?

CSS document says that a `%` value of `margin` property applies a margin in % of the width of the containing element. Also my `#mydiv` element is not nested. So `2%` margin of `#mydiv`'s width `500px` will be calculated to 10px which is the same value in my previous code.

Please explain why this difference is seen here?

Comment: To begin with, the `devicePixelRatio` property https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/devicePixelRatio differ from devices to devices, and also from a browser to another. Btw, percentages are then not very reliable, this is not the only possible explanation, but just try using `vh` and `vw` CSS units instead to maximize consistency between devices.

Comment: Because when you apply margin (%) to your div, it uses div's parent's height and width. In you case that parent would be `body`. Resize your browser and you see it.

Comment: @YSFKBDY As per my best knowledge, element's only width is considered while calculating margin in %.

Comment: no, the element's **containing block** is the reference for percentage calculation. It's never the element itself

Comment: @TemaniAfif That's what I said. Sachin, did you try what I said? You can find detailed info on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin#values

Comment: @YSFKBDY Yes I tried by resizing my browser window when margin % was applied. I also checked suggested link. Now I found the reason! Thanks dude.